# Locally equivalent measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a metric space and $\mu,\nu$ a Borel measures on it. Suppose that there exist $R>0$ and a constant $C>0$ such that for all $r<R$ and $x\in X$ we have that $$C^{-1}\nu(B(x,r))\leqslant\mu(B(x,r))\leqslant C\nu(B(x,r)).$$
Is it then true that the norms of $L^2(X,\mu)$ and $L^2(X,\nu)$ are equivalent in the sense that $A^{-1}\|f\|_{L^2(X,\mu)}\leqslant\|f\|_{L^2(X,\nu)}\leqslant A\|f\|_{L^2(X,\mu)}$ for all $f$?

Comment: Quick note: the hypothesis _signifies_ $\nu(f) \asymp \mu(f)$ when $f$ is the indicator for  a ball; by linearity the same is true (with same constants) for linear combination of indicators of balls. Maybe approximate the indicator of a close set by such functions from above?

Comment: I guess you could do something like that if you had something like a dyadic partition, which -under some hypothesis on $X$- you do. If you don't have such partition, maybe it's possible to construct a counter-example.